# How prevent c# form losing focus inside MDI parent?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several forms which have the same MdiParent.

In particular two of them, let's call them `formA` and `formB`. `formB` is called (displayed) from `formA`.

When both are opened in the MDIParent, I would like to keep `formB` on top of `formA` **all the time** until `formB` is closed

I tried using Deactivated and Focus on `formB` but it is not doing what I want.

Can you help me do that ?

Comment: Use `ShowDialog` for that

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Hemal it says I can't call showdialog since it is a child of the MDI parent

Comment: @Hemal  but Ok  you are right. I'm going to take it out of the MDI. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formB.ShowDialog()` will help you get `formB` on top everytime.